# Improve Pagespeed when using Facebook Pixel

Tags: pagespeed, facebook-pixel

I am creating a general facebook integration solution, which uses the facebook pixel, however I am in a situation where if a use the facebook pixel it instantly reduces the pagespeed which is also a requirement for me.

I am using the PageSpeed Insghts to measure my pagespeed, and by adding the facebook pixel my Largest Contentful Paint gets a hit and I get this opportunity showing the facebook pixel load as the problem:
[image]

The only solution I found is by adding a `setTimeout(fb, 3000)` around the pixel script so that it only gets loaded after the page is fully rendered, however I am concerned about this solution since this will largely postpone the facebook load and it may cause some problems for some of my users.

Anyone knows any other way to fix this hit in pagespeed using facebook pixel?

Comment: Where exactly do you have the FB pixel initialized, how are you measuring page speed reduction - TTI, Pageload?

Comment: Hi Ramakay, I am using the PageSpeed Insights, for now I am using it in the header

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the clarification.

Your best bet is to use `defer` in your script embed vs arbitrary timeouts, this means your critical rendering path and interactivity are unaffected. LCP specifically should improve as your application rendering remains unaffected by the pixel.

via MDN:

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.

Note: if you are not observing specific interaction issues and are purely focused on addressing LCP numbers, deferring may meet the need.